# Unclear SecurityException when using Android Service Backup (Cloud Backup)

Tags: android, permissions, android-backup-service

I try to use my application, which contains usage of [Android Backup Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) with my own `BackupAgent`, on **Android Emulator**. But backup **doesn't work**, despite of permission written in AndroidManifest.xml.

**Permission:** <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BACKUP"/>

**Warning in log:** 09-17 09:05:58.553: WARN/PackageManager(73): Not granting permission android.permission.BACKUP to package my.package (protectionLevel=3 flags=0x1be46)

**Exception in log** (when I try to call [requestRestore()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#RequestingRestore)):
java.lang.SecurityException: getCurrentTransport: Neither user 10040 nor current process has android.permission.BACKUP.

What's wrong in my code?

UPD: My manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="my.package">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BACKUP"/>

<application android:name="my.package.MyApplicationName" android:backupAgent="my.package.MyBackupAgent">

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" android:value="my_backup_api_key">

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try to require the permission for the whole app, also are you sure you build the project after changing manifest?

Comment: I'm sure I have build it, and my permission is for the whole app.

Comment: can you please post the whole androidManifest file?

Comment: I've post it in update of my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : Neither user 10066 nor current process has android.permission.BACKUP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735925/error-neither-user-10066-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-backup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official Android documentation of [Manifest permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) knows nothing about permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BACKUP"/>
```

So, you should remove it from your Manifest. [Android Backup Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) **doesn't** require additional permissions.

However, specified permission can be used, but only by "system" applications, because it requires `PROTECTION_SIGNATURE` or `PROTECTION_SIGNATURE_OR_SYSTEM` [level of permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html).

Such permission needed only when calling method [BackupManager.dataChanged(String packageName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupManager.html#dataChanged%28java.lang.String%29), but usually this method is not needed when implementing Backup Service.

Comment: It's very important to call BackupManager.dataChanged.  It does not require android.permission.BACKUP.

Answer (score 1):

The `android.permission.BACKUP` permission is not needed for normal `BackupAgent` operations.  Remove it from your manifest - though it shouldn't stop your `BackupAgent` from working.

Make sure to call `BackupManager.dataChanged()` method when you need to do a backup otherwise your BackupAgent will be called once but never again.  It does not need `android.permission.BACKUP` either.